# How To make Buttons Clickable in ListView Header

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, layout-inflater

I have two buttons in ListView Header and I want to detect button is clicked from the header. how can I do this..
here is my code:

header_list.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<Button
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/b1" />
<Button
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/b2" />
</LinearLayout>
```

in java code I have done this

```
LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
View mTop = inflater.inflate(R.layout.header_list, null);
listview.addHeaderView(mTop);
```

Comment: so what an issue? normally call object of that button and set onClickListner.

Comment: What is ur exact question? Is u needed the button click function just initial the button by Button _btnb1 = (Button) mTop.findViewById(R.id.b1);

Comment: thank you  Nithinlal, now it works....

Comment: Sorry to be a pain in the arse, but... how would this vary if used within a fragment? @NaveedAli

Comment: @JosueGalindo inever tried, But I think same way should work as given below...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add listener to these buttons.

```
btnB1 = (Button) mTop.findViewById(R.id.b1);
btnB1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Your code.

        }
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

```
LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
View mTop = inflater.inflate(R.layout.header_list, null);
listview.addHeaderView(mTop);
Button _btnb1 = (Button) mTop.findViewById(R.id.b1);
_btnb1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // Your code.

    }
});

Button _btnb2 = (Button) mTop.findViewById(R.id.b2);
_btnb2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // Your code.

    }
});
```

Try this code